# Is there similar method like Document.goToByIdAsync for office 2013 in office.js

Tags: office-addins, office-2013, office-js, office-app

Is there similar method like Document.goToByIdAsync for office 2013 in office.js, i see that this method is added in api version 1.1, which works for office 2016.

I want to go to specific cell or range in office 2013 desktop version using office addins, is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.goToByIdAsync is supported in Office 2016 and Office 2013.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: i was trying to use in onpremise version of office. is it supported there too..actually it didnot work for me.

Comment: Is your Office 2013 desktop up to date? Support for APIs gets added with patches.